# Passport Not calling callback

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Using passport for the first time and I realize that when I log data inside the strategy callback it doesn't get displayed in the console, is this how it works or am I doing something wrong?

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log('this should be displayed');
    done(profile)
  }
);
```

Route looks like this:

```
app.get('/api/v1/authenticate/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by calling authenticate like this:

```
passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_likes', 'user_birthday'],
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:1337" + req.url
}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
    // Do something
})(req, res, next);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `passReqToCallback:true`, your callback will be called with `req` as the first argument.

You should call it as 
`function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)`, 
so `done` will be in the correct position.

EDIT:
I realize you mean the main callback.
It's a two step process, so process.env.CALLBACK_URL should also point to a route with the passport middleware registered.

From the docs:

If `callbackURL: "http://yourdormain:3000/auth/google/callback",`

```
app.get( '/auth/google/callback', 
    passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
        successRedirect: '/auth/google/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/google/failure'
}));
```